# How to Edit the NBT Data of a Minecraft Forge Player

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am a beginner to Forge Modding and I'm having a problem adding a custom NBT Tag to a Player in an overridden `Item.finishUsingItem` method.

There seems to be nothing on the Forge API website on NBTs and anything about NBTs that I've found all seems to be outdated so i got to a bit of an impasse

Github [here](https://github.com/Jade-Prince/Necromancy-Mod)!

My current code in the `finishUsingItem` method looks like this:

```java
if (pLivingEntity instanceof Player pPlayer)
{
    CompoundTag entityNBT = pPlayer.serializeNBT();
    if (!entityNBT.contains("necromancy_level"))
    {
        NLevelTag levelTag = new NLevelTag(1, 0);
        levelTag.levelUp();
        entityNBT.put("necromancy_level", levelTag);
        // looking for code here to set player's NBT to entityNBT
    } else
    {
        NLevelTag levelTag = (NLevelTag) entityNBT.get("necromancy_level");
        levelTag.levelUp(5);
    }
}
```

My `NLevelTag` has two ints:

```java
private int level;
private int levelXP;

public NLevelTag(int _level, int _levelXP)
{
    this.level = _level;
    this.levelXP = _levelXP;
}
```

and a `levelUp` method:

```java
public void levelUp()
{
    this.levelXP++;
    LOGGER.debug("XP leveled up to " + this.levelXP);
}
```

Note: levelUp has a separate overload which takes an int and calls the above method that number of times.

When I load Forge and eat the item I can get the Player NBT data from the item but it never has the field that it should have added.

Is there something I have missed about adding NBTs to entities?

Or can you just not do that?

Comment: Off-topic comment, but your variables names should be reversed. Prefix the members with the underscore and the parameters shouldn't have any decorations

Comment: Also I found [this](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/9156-help-adding-nbt-data-to-the-player/) with a Google search. Seems like they have a similar problem

Comment: What does serializeNBT do exactly? From the name, I'd assume it just gives you a copy of the NBT, but you're using it as if writes to it will automatically propagate back to where you got it from.

Comment: yes I've realised that is what it does! sorry for confusion